# Infinite loop process inside Django application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to make a process inside my django application that just after the application starts, it will randomly take one record from `Products` table (which contains f.e. name, price and rating) and set it into another table named `SingleProduct`.

The process should run inside infinite loop and replace the single product inside `SingleProduct` table every 15 minutes.

How can I do stuff like this? What should I looking for?

What do I need it for? I want to display some random product from the database on my home page every 15 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a scheduled job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ajax for this.

Here is an Example:

In your template:
Import JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then at the bottom you can do something like this

```
{% block script %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
    // If you wish to refresh the page after calling the function
    // uncomment the line below
    // location.reload();
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '{% url 'homepage' %}',
        success: function() {
          console.log('{{randomint}}')
        }
      });
    }, 1000) // this is in milisenconds, 1000 = 1sec
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

This will call the `url` "`'homepage'`" every second,

url:

```
path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
```

view:

```
def homepage(request):
    template = loader.get_template('jsondata.html')
    #
    # put your code here
    #
    randomint = randint(1, 100) # this is just for example purposes
    context = {
        'randomint': randomint,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Note: This is just an example and will not work out of the box...

Hope this somewhat answers your question.

Extra info: [Django URL in Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337731/using-the-django-url-tag-in-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wrote it wrong. I know that I can do this on the client side and send every 15 min request to server to get a new random product, but I need to do this on server side because I want to have every user the same random product.

Comment: @somenoobyquestions ahh... sorry, then i cant help you..

Comment: @somenoobyquestions maybe [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434641/how-to-loop-a-function-to-perform-a-task-every-15-minutes-on-the-0-15-30-45-min) or [this documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) can be of help